# Forgotten Pin 1

Tags: visual

[image]

I have forgotten my 6 digit pin code again! My fish are always trying to tell me something but I can’t figure out was they are trying to tell me. Please help me find my pin code!

Comment: I love the artwork you did for this :)

Comment: Very simple and thoughtful. Well done!

Comment: @Grizzly25 I agree with the other comments.  Thank you for this very nice puzzle!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your PIN is

> 694711

Fishplanation:

> For each totally-real breed of fish depicted, take the letter from its name corresponding to the number of bubbles
>
> ```
> Sword
> lIon
> Xray
> lemoN (thanks @ladyofcats)
> fIre
> aNgel
> archEr
> Flounder (or Flat?)
> dOg
> bUll
> zebRa
> Saw
> bonE
> loVe
> pinEapple
> clowN
> parrOt
> aNgler
> whalE
> fOx
> raiNbow
> jElly
> ```

Comment: Nice work! The fourth might be a lemonfish.

Comment: @ladyofcats Ah, yes, that definitely makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your PIN clearly is

> 123456

Explanation:

> You're happily mixing freshwater fish, saltwater fish, building equipment, fruit and even mammals (both aquatic and non-aquatic) in the same aquarium, so you're probably - with all due respect - a person of limited wits.
>
>  It is well known that as such you're highly likely to choose a PIN of [a certain style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JNGI1dI-e8), and the example given in the linked video can trivially be extended to six digits, ending up 123456. (Amazing! That's the same PIN I have on my Stack Exchange account!)

Comment: +1 purely for the President Scrooge reference.

Comment: You make some good points, though I think I'd lean more towards "mad scientist" than "idiot" for some of these.  I think that parrot (Norwegian Blue?) must have *really* been pining for the fjords though.  And just FYI @ImmortalBlue, it's 'Skroob' (an anagram of Brooks).

Comment: @hagfy Remarkable bird, the Norwegian Blue. Beautiful plumage.